# Disable required auth for action

Tags: php

A developer made for me a website where you can vote for things only if you are logged in. At first, when we launched the website it was not a requirement and I would like to go back to that.

I found a file - Voting.php:

```
class Voting
{
    public function getKey()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return auth()->user()->id;
        } else {
            return request()->ip();
        }
    }
    public function getVotes($key)
    {
        $int = config('app.settings.vote_interval');
        $votes = Cache::get('votes::' . $key);
        if ($votes) {
            $now = time();
            foreach ($votes as $key => $value) {
                if ($value < $now - $int) {
                    unset($votes[$key]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $votes = [];
        }
        return $votes;
    }
}
```

Am I looking into the right file?
Can I get some help to disable the required auth for voting?

Thank you!

Comment: Even if it was really the file. We can’t say for sure how many other files are going to be affected by the change!.

Answer (score 1):

From the limited information you provided. I am not sure how much this would help. Having said that, here is my attempt to help.

```
class Voting
{
    public function getKey()
    {
        return request()->ip();
    }

    public function getVotes($key)
    {
        $int = config('app.settings.vote_interval');
        $votes = Cache::get('votes::' . $key);
        if ($votes) {
            $now = time();
            foreach ($votes as $key => $value) {
                if ($value < $now - $int) {
                    unset($votes[$key]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $votes = [];
        }
        return $votes;
    }
}
```

Comment: _..here is my attempt to help..._ Vagabond is trying to say that he removed the auth check in this line `if (auth()->check()) {`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it did not worked. I got error 500 on website after deleting that line of code.

Comment: Need more information. What do the logs say ?